# Multiple List Views in Android

Tags: android, listview

In my android app I have two List Views and two buttons.On clicking first button, first List View will be visible and on second button second List View will be visible.In one List View I will have list of items and in second List View there will be ADD button. Now clicking on ADD button my first List View will be visible and user can select items to add in second List View. I have done it successfully. But my problem is, by clicking on second button List View is appearing  but there are no data which are added from First List View. Below is my code.
What am I missing?

```
final ListView lv = getListView();
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
final View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.footer, null);
lv.addFooterView(header, null, false);

btnCollege.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         String listItems[] = {};
         final ArrayAdapter<String> string = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
         lv.setAdapter(string);

        Button btnAdd = (Button) header.findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);

        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                 if (j == 0) 
                 {
                     lv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                     header.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                     j = 1;
                 }


                 else if (j == 1) 
                 {
                     lv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                     header.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                     j = 0;
                    }

                 else {}


                lv1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                            String selected = lv1.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString();
                            string.add(selected);
                            string.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            setListAdapter(string);


                    }
                });

            }
        });


    }
});
```

Comment: you will need to extend the ArrayAdapter in order to update the adapter with  notifyDataSetChanged() method i guess

Comment: I am not getting what are you saying about? Can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

The view is not getting updated. use handlers for updating listview. That would help you solve the issue

Comment: how? can you give me some examples...Or code...Just small hint and I will hit it...